# Cannot run program keytool Using Java Spring Runtime exec

Tags: java, spring, runtime.exec, keytool

I have ran this command into my java code where everything with `openssl` works fine

```
String[] keyStoreCmd = { "keytool", "-importkeystore", "-deststorepass", password, "-destkeypass", password, "-destkeystore", String.format("%s.keystore", userCertificatePath + name), "-srckeystore", String.format("%s.pfx", userCertificatePath + name), "-srcstoretype", "PKCS12", "-srcstorepass", password, "-alias", name };

Process p5 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(keyStoreCmd);

exhaustInputStream(p5);
p5.waitFor();
```

I've generated `.pfx` and other `.crt`, `.csr` and `.key` using `openssl` that works fine and all these files exist there at path at `userCertificatePath` variable, The issue is when I execute above command it throws following error

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "keytool": error=2, No such file or directory

P.S: When I output the string and run the command directly it works and generate the `.keystore`

Comment: Looks like the Path to keytool is not set if you run your Java program.

Comment: One way is to add the complete path to your command

Comment: I would rather add it to path

Comment: How and where do I add `keytool` to `PATH`

Comment: Which os do you use?

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, its ubuntu

Comment: Look here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/63250/how-to-set-environmental-variable-path